# What does "Most Score By" mean at the end of a round in BF:BC2?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

Here is a random screen from Internet with online match result in Bad Company 2:

[image]

One would though that "Most Score By" would simply be a kill counter for this round for the best weapon, but even on this screen numbers clearly don't add up.

What does number "27" mean here? I've been trying to figure out mystery of this section since the release date, and still cannot see any connections. Maybe it is just a bug?

Answer (score 8):

That means you got the most score by using that weapon or vehicle while you were in that room, it carries over from match to match unlike that KD which is just from the previous match. It further breaks it down by how many kills you had with it, distance driven, and how many people you ran over.

Comment: Thanks capt. obvious, but how I could get 27 kills with a tank if I have 22 kills total?

Comment: Okay @serg... that is kills you have gotten with that vehicle since being in that particular room not just the kills you got during the previous match. You probably joined at the end of another match before starting the one where you got 22 kills?

Comment: No offense, but I think you are just guessing here and never played BC2 online. You would clearly know that it is not the case - it is not kill counter in a match, it is not a kill counter for a room, it is not a kill counter in a session, it is not a kill counter in a day. Any more guesses?

Comment: No I just didn't read the last part of the post :P no need to get so upset. After reading the full thing I did quick google because your right it, doesn't make any sense and found the answer so I shared it with you. The hostility...

Comment: @serg I guess they must all be "guessing" as well: http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/4547711.page

Comment: And you know what your right Kils: ## could not possible be counting the number of kills, you really need relax a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

I cant confirm this but I have a feeling that its to do with the total server kill count.

It might be that at the end of the round the server figures out the weapon you have scored highest with and then combines all of the other players stats for that weapon as well. So in this case you got 22 kills in the tank which means all of the other players on the server (or maybe on your team / squad) had a combined total of 5 kills.

I still dont know why they would show it like this ... maybe to illustrate your personal contribution to that particular class?

Like I said I might be completely wrong but thats the best explanation I have come up with so far. Although as with most EA games I wouldnt be suprised if it is a bug ... I was blowing up the 2nd set of Mcom stations in Arica harbour through the roof with C4 for a good 7 months before they fixed that.

Comment: Careful, this guy is very touchy about guesses +1 for good guess though :D.

Answer (score 1):

The counter for "Most Kills By" are over whole server session, while the kill counter on top is just for one round. So if you played more than one round on same server, the numbers will not add up.